# Elasticsearch 7.10.2 doesn't bind application.properties variables on Mac M1

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, apple-m1

I'm facing a weird issue. I have 2 laptops, one running under Windows where everything works fine and on the other side, a Mac Mini M1.

Assuming, I'm developing a basic Spring Boot application with Elasticsearch as Repository.
In the `application.yml`, as usual I have the following properties :

```
spring:
  elasticsearch:
    rest:
      uris: https://dummy-cloud-provider.cloud.com:12833
      username: myusername
      password: mypassword
```

But everytime I want to start the application on my Mac, I have the following error :

```
2021-06-23 15:55:51.972 ERROR [reactor-http-nio-3] r.c.p.Operators - Operator called default onErrorDropped
reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.NoReachableHostException: Host 'localhost:9200' not reachable. Cluster state is offline.
Caused by: org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.NoReachableHostException: Host 'localhost:9200' not reachable. Cluster state is offline.
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.SingleNodeHostProvider.lambda$lookupActiveHost$3(SingleNodeHostProvider.java:101)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:102)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:220)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2397)
    ...
```

I don't understand why it always skip my `application.yml` variables and try to reach `localhost:9200`.

I hope someone can help me :)

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

This is not a Spring Data Elasticsearch problem, but a Spring Boot problem. Spring Data Elasticsearch does not use application properties to set anything up.

Looking at the configuration it seems that you want to set up a imperative (non-reactive) client connection to Elasticsearch?

The stacktrace shows that the failing call is done by the **reactive** client.

I suspect that you have the reactive Spring libraries (webflux) in the classpath and Spring boot actuator. And Spring Boot then configures a reactive client for the actuator using the default of *localhost:9200*.

I can't tell for sure without seeing your maven/gradle setup, but this for me is most possible explanation for this error.

Comment: Indeed, I edit my question with the solution